# Retrieving intermediate features from pytorch torch.hub.load

Tags: pytorch

I have a Net object instantiated in pytorch via torch.hub.load:

```
model = torch.hub.load('facebookresearch/pytorchvideo', 'slowfast_r50', pretrained=True)
```

The final layer is a projection to a 400-dim vector. Is there a way to get the pentultimate layer instead during a forward pass?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, easiest way is to switch the layer with [`torch.nn.Identity`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Identity.html) (which simply returns it's inputs unchanged):

Line below changes this submodule:

```
(6): ResNetBasicHead(
      (dropout): Dropout(p=0.5, inplace=False)
      (proj): Linear(in_features=2304, out_features=400, bias=True)
      (output_pool): AdaptiveAvgPool3d(output_size=1)
    )
```

to `Identity`:

```
model.blocks[6] = torch.nn.Identity()
```

as you probably don't want to keep the `Dropout` anyway (you might only change `proj` or any other part of the network as needed).

Answer (score 0):

Use "create_feature_extractor", first you should update torch>=1.11.0

```
model = torch.hub.load('facebookresearch/pytorchvideo', 'x3d_m', pretrained=True)
preds = model(inputs)
```

to 'create_feature_extractor'

```
model = torch.hub.load('facebookresearch/pytorchvideo', 'x3d_m', pretrained=True)
from torchvision.models.feature_extraction import create_feature_extractor
# print(model)
# for (name, module) in model.named_modules():
#     print(name, module)
model = create_feature_extractor(model, {'blocks.5.dropout': 'feat'})
preds = model(inputs)
feat = preds.get('feat')
```

You can use the model layer name instead of 'blocks.5.dropout'